# SDL memory usage

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sdl, valgrind

I'm writing a very basic SDL application, but when I run it through valgrind, it reports several lost blocks apparently related to the SDL library (before you ask it, I do call SDL_Quit, or more precisely I call `atexit(SDL_Quit)`). Here is an example:

```
==2525== 192 (16 direct, 176 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 107 of 131
==2525==    at 0x4C25502: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2525==    by 0x644244A: ??? (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x6442989: ??? (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x64440A2: ??? (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x6444915: _XlcCreateLC (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x6462B5F: _XlcDefaultLoader (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x644C325: _XOpenLC (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x644C467: _XlcCurrentLC (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x644C4BD: XSetLocaleModifiers (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==2525==    by 0x4E69EED: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==2525==    by 0x4E6A57F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==2525==    by 0x4E59E00: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
```

I searched here on StackOverflow and found a similar question. The answer was that apparently, there are some small buffers allocated within the library which the writers never care to free. My question is, what is the motivation of such an approach? Why allocate something and then deliberately not `free()` it?

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in the library? Not all code is written perfectly. It's very possible they accidentally forgot to free some memory in there, since it is a very large library.

Comment: Don't mean to double-comment, but I forgot to add: If it really is a memory leak, you might want to report this to the developers of SDL. However, Eelke does bring up a valid point that they may be just waiting to the very end to actually deallocate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buffers are needed till the end of the program there is no need to free them. When a program exits all memory it was using is freed by the OS anyway. If the program bothered to free the blocks before exiting it would only serve to slow down the exiting of the program.

Comment: That's likely to be the reason, but I think it's a lousy reason, especially for a library, and I'd discourage anybody from following it. First, it's bad because OSes aren't guaranteed to free the memory; generally older ones or ones without a memory manager won't. Second, it's bad because of exactly this question: tools like Valgrind will throw a fit, making it very hard to debug your own code. Third, it's bad for a library because shutting down a library is not necessarily the end of the process. If the client asks your library to shut down, it's polite to free all the memory.

Comment: I agree it is not good practice especially for a library, I was just saying it isn't necessarily something to worry about. Many applications don't clean up there singletons because worrying about when to free them is not worth it.